# IBM MobileFirst Analytics console not synchronize with operations console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have a push notification issue with mobilefirst 7.1.

When the mobile device subscribes and receive the push notification message, i see the logged data in the operations console. But I don't see any data in the analytics console. Maybe it doesn't synchronize each other? But the device's data does exist. It only syncs with the device in operations console.

Comment: What is your installation's full version and build number?

Comment: My Product Version Is 7.1.0.00-20150807-0630

Comment: I suggest to attempt again with the latest available iFix, which is from October and contains several Analytics-relate fixes.

Comment: You mean that IBM have the fix pack for 7.1 version from October ?

Comment: Not Fix Pack, iFix. You can download it from the IBM Fix Central website.

Comment: Ok ! thank you Idan. I will try it right now and let you know the result tomorrow. It take me a lot of time to find solutions.

Comment: Are you seeing any data at all in your analytics console? Sessions, server logs, client logs, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, we do not currently log push notification data in the analytics console. However, our dev team will be looking into it as we see this is an issue.